# Python: ambiguities when (un-)pickling a dict-based tree

Tags: python, dictionary, tree, pickle

I have a simple tree structure where each node can have several children which are accessed through keys (+ some payload stored in `value`):

```
class NodeDict(dict):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    self.parent = parent
    self.value = None
  def AddChild(self, label):
    self[label] = NodeDict(self)
    return self[label]

class TreeDict:
  def __init__(self):
    self.root = NodeDict(None)
  def ToString(self, level, node):
    res = ":" + str(node.value) + "\n"
    for k, v in node.items():
      res += "  "*level + str(k) + self.ToString(level + 1, v)
    return res
  def __str__(self):
    return self.ToString(1, self.root)
```

When I try to pickle such a tree I have the problem that it is not correctly unpickled as the following example shows:

```
class Obj:
  def __init__(self, v):
    self.v = v
  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.v)

t = TreeDict()
a = t.root.AddChild(Obj("A"))
b = a.AddChild(Obj("B"))
c = b.AddChild(Obj("C"))
d = b.AddChild(Obj("D"))
e = a.AddChild(Obj("E"))

print t

import cPickle
cPickle.dump(t,  open("test.dat", "w"))
t = cPickle.load(open("test.dat", "r"))
print t
```

The tree looks like this before

```
:None
  A:None
    E:None
    B:None
      C:None
      D:None
```

and like this after pickling and unpickling:

```
:None
  A:None
    B:None
      B:None
        D:None
        C:None
      E:None
    E:None
```

The problem arises from the fact that I am using `Obj` as `label`s in the tree (i.e. as keys in the `dict`). (It also fails when using e.g. strings instead of `Obj` if they are not all mutually different.)

How could this be changed to work as intended?

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour if you use the pickle package rather than cpickle?

Comment: Can you make you classes new-style by making TreeDict and Obj inherit from object? Does the behaviour change?

Comment: `pickle` fails already on saving (maybe rightfully...)

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe you should convert your second comment into an answer ;) Would you know why this solves the problem?

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig Your code works for me (Python 2.7.3 / Linux). What Python version / OS are you using?

Comment: @Aya: The same! (Python 2.7.3 on Linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When subclassing builtin types like `dict` or using new style classes you should use at least the [pickle protocol 2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format). The default for python2 is still 0, which can have problems with these.

When using `dump(t, open("test.dat", "wb"), protocol=2)` your code works with `cPickle` and with `pickle` alike.

And remember the [remark about opening the files in binary mode](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL).

Answer (score 0):

If this is still not working (see Aya's comment), is using another tree structure an option for you? If so, here is a script [to pickle DOM tree structure](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/355487-pickle-python-objects-to-a-dom-tree-and-vice-versa/).